# Unity game UI messing up on iOS devices

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, unity-game-engine, build

First of all, I am completely new to preparing iOS build using Xcode(In fact, I have rarely worked on a apple device). 
Secondly, until now I was preparing my builds using unity cloud build.

My unity game was working fine until now. I usually test my build with aspect ratio of 9:16. But even when i change that to 1536*2048(ipad resolution), it renders fine(though it looks a bit imperfect). This is all with unity editor in play mode.

But as soon as I run my code on actual ios device, it gets completely destroyed and messed up. It works fine on android device.

This was not the case a few days ago and the game was working fine even on ipad. Can someone please give any insights about where I could have have gone wrong?

Is there some particular catch with xcode version or unity versions or compatibility between the two.

Comment: "it gets completely destroyed and messed up" You did not describe your problem...What do you mean by messed up? It would make sense to provide a screen shot of the good and the "messed up" version of the app. Also provide your Unity version and iOS version.

Comment: As in, panels shifts drastically to one side and some panels don't show up at all.

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots?